# R shiny object scoping

Tags: r, shiny, scoping

I'm trying to access an object(`a<-get(obj1,envir=parent.environment())`) residing in the calling environment from the called environment `myf` and I can't get it working. Error I'm getting is `Object obj1 not found`. I tried `parent.frame()`also. Any ideas?

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = textOutput("test1"),
  server = function(input, output) {
    myf <- function(x) {
      a <- get(obj1, envir = parent.environment())
      return(paste0(x,a))
    }
    output$test1 <- renderText({
      obj1 <- "testing"
      a <- lapply(c("a","b","c"), myf)
      return(paste(unlist(a), collapse = ","))
    })
  }
)
```

NOTE : I do NOT want to create obj1 using `obj1<<-` as it creates in Global Environment and is available for all sessions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct solution is that you have three problems: First of all, you need to quote `"obj1"` like this

```
get("obj1", envir = ...)
```

Secondly, `parent.environment()` is not a function. It doesn't exist.

Thirdly, you need to understand environment and calling frames a little bit to know how this works (it has nothing to do with Shiny). What you want to use is `parent.frame(2)` (being inside an `lapply` adds a layer)

So to modify your original code, this is the solution:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = textOutput("test1"),
  server = function(input, output) {
    myf <- function(x) {
      a <- get("obj1", envir = parent.frame(2))
      return(paste0(x,a))
    }
    output$test1 <- renderText({
      obj1 <- "testing"
      a <- lapply(c("a","b","c"), myf)
      return(paste(unlist(a), collapse = ","))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Yikes, I didn't even notice that `"obj1"` wasn't quoted. No wonder!

Comment: I only noticed it when I fixed the parent.environment issue to be the correct environment, and was still getting the error, and thought "but I'm in the correct env..... why!" "ah.."

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed explanation `daattali`. I should read more about calling frames - any good links?

Comment: Yes - Hadley of course :p  http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html  is an excellent 30 minute read that will really teach you a lot

Comment: @Sri I'm glad you got your answer, but let this be a warning about relying on scoping instead of passing in arguments explicitly.

Comment: @daattali I'm actually not clear on why the `get` is even necessary here. For instance, `f <- function(x) x + y; y <- 3; f(2)` works just fine.

Comment: @ssdecontrol the example you just gave is very different. `y` gets stored in the global, and inside the `f` function when `y` is referenced, it can be easily found by looking in its enclosing environment. However, in the case of this shiny app, `obj1` is created inside the environment that calls `myf`, but it is NOT the enclosing environment (where `myf` is declared`. You need to understand that parent vs enclosing environment are different things. Read the link I posted to Hadley's book. If variables would look in the environment of whoever called it, you would get non-deterministic code= bad

Comment: @daattali I have read that writeup but it's been a while. So `f <- function(x) x + y; g <- function(x) { y <- 3; f(x) }; g(2)` might be a MWE for this behavior. The idea being that `f` is called from the environment in `g`, but the environment in `g` is not an ancestor of `f`. Right?

Comment: Kinda. Variable lookup happens according to where the function was DEFINED, not where it is CALLED. `f` is defined in the global env, so any variables inside of it have to be found either inside `f` or in global env. Same goes for `g`. If you defined another function `h` inside `f`, then variables inside `h` could use any variable from either `h` or `f` or global.  Reading his article again would be a good refresher

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but there' a simple workaround: explicitly pass `obj1` to `myf`:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = textOutput("test1"),
  server = function(input, output) {

## myf now takes two arguments, x and a:
    myf <- function(x, a) {
      return(paste0(x, a))
    }

    output$test1 <- renderText({
      obj1 <- "testing"

## Now you can just pass obj1 as a second argument to myf
##  without worrying about scoping:
      a <- lapply(c("a","b","c"), myf, obj1)

      return(paste(unlist(a), collapse = ","))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, do you also have scoping solution too - I'm interested to see what the scoping solution is ?

Comment: You can see my answer to see the correct solution rather than a workaround